# bash referencing a variable inside another one

Tags: bash

I am trying to reference a variable within another one but its not working for me

```
$ bond0_enable='yes'
$ echo $bond0_enable
yes
$ i=0
$ echo $bond$i_enable
```

I want to reference the whole variable to read $i, how is this done please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, for example:

```
$ bond0_enable='yes'
$ i=0
$ d=bond${i}_enable
$ echo ${!d}           <----- key point, ${!name} makes it
yes
```